# how to add Limit() to pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have two tables `products` and `categories` and a pivot table `category_product`.

I have added relation in `Product.php` is below.

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

I have added relation in `Category.php` is below.

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Both are working fine.

But what I want is, I want to take all the `categories` which has products and the products should not return more than 6 records. 
Meaning I have a two `categories` **Music, Movies** and both have more than 50+ products.
The code should be return only 6 products for both **Music, Movies** categories.

This is what I tried,

```
    Category::with(['products' => function ($query){
        return $query->select()->limit(6);
    }, 'products.properties'])
    ->whereHas('products', function ($query){
        return $query->select()->limit(6);
    })->when($slug, function($query) use($slug){
        $query->whereIn('slug', $slug);
    })->get();
```

and this,

```
 Category::addSelect([
               'products' => Product::select('id')->whereColumn('products.id', 'categories.id')->orderBy('id')->limit(6)
           ])->when($slug, function($query) use($slug){
              $query->whereIn('slug', $slug);
           })->get()
```

Second try returns error,

`"stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"`

I am using laravel 6.

Thanks in advance, any answers and suggestion welcome.

**Added My Answer Below**

Answer (score 1):

please use this. Also add all your logics to eloquent, not in controller.

```
public function categories()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->limit(6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my question. Please have a check and please advice me if any better way to solve it.(mainly I want to reduce the number of queries)

**The solution is**

```
public function getProductsBasedOnCategory(array $slug){
    $categories = Category::select()->when($slug, function($query) use($slug){
        $query->whereIn('slug', $slug);
    })->get();
    $res = new Collection();
    foreach ($categories as $category){
        $category->products = $category->products()->limit(6)->get();
        $res->push($category);
    }
    return $res;
}
```

This function executing queries how many categories I have.

If I have 10 categories, its executing 10 queries. Exclude `$categories query`

Is this answer is good or you have any better solution. I want to reduce the number of queries execution.

Please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

you can use like below.

```
$cat = Category::with('products')->when($slug, function($query) use($slug){
                $query->whereIn('slug', $slug);
            })->get();

            foreach ($cat as $key => $value) {
                $value->products->first();
            }
```

Comment: yeah, but what If my category has huge products?  I dont want a huge collection. `$cat ` would be huge. I just want to return only 6 products.